# Server-Sent Events using Play 2 Java

Tags: java, playframework, java-7, playframework-2.3, ebean

I'm trying to implement Server-sent events in the Play 2 framework (version 2.3.9) using Java.  I'd like for an event to be sent to the client every time a "Message" entity is saved to the database. The entity should be sent to the client in Json format.

```
Message message = new Message();
//some code to populate bean here
message.save(); //save to db

//What do I do with message here?
```

I was thinking of making a service class that will send events.

```
public class SSEService {

    public static void sendEvent(String data, String id, String name){
        EventSource eventSource = new EventSource() {
            @Override
            public void onConnected() {
              //no idea what to do here
            }
        };
        EventSource.Event event = new EventSource.Event(data, id, name);
        eventSource.send(event);
    }
}
```

I would then call SSEService.sendEvent() after saving the message.  Am I on the right track? What does data, id, and name correspond to in the Event constructor?

Can someone provide a good example in Java 7?

Comment: Exactly which version of Play are you using?

Comment: I am always choosing WebSocket over SSE so can't really give a good advice here but this should help: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/1282/commits/723d7f038e7d294e66c6da2f5a3689986c167552 (Commit with sample code) and http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/sse-chat-template-java (Activator template for SSE in Java)